# Can G Suite administrators view Chrome history?

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator, google-search-history

Simple question here.

Given the scenario:

1. Org uses G Suite
2. User logs to Chrome on their workstation using their company G Suite account
3. User browses to Stack Exchange

Can G Suite admins see that the user browsed to Stack Exchange since it saves to Chrome's history and Chrome is logged into the G Suite account?

Comment: Is the workstation a managed device (the company owns the device and have administrator privileges on it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a few Google Product Form posts this does **not** look to be a feature of G Suite. So no, administrators can not view their users' Chrome history.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/uAHDhsaOcLM
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/uuKe3t0kAWU
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/Vde9RQd4WhE